# Multiple 'And' on the same column

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering how to multiple ands in a SQL query. So in the example below (which works).

```
select distinct 
    Room_Facilities.Room_ID 
from 
    [Room_Facilities] 
inner join 
    [Rooms] on Room_Facilities.Room_ID = Rooms.Room_ID
where 
    Building_ID = 'LDS' 
    and Room_Facilities.Facility_ID  = 'C'
```

I would like to add another 'and' so that the room selected has the facilities 'C' As well as 'V'. I have tried this, however, then it returns null. At the moment, it only works with one of the and conditions of the Facility_ID but i would like multiple (in the example below there is 2, it does not work, only works with 1).

```
select distinct 
    Room_Facilities.Room_ID 
from 
    [Room_Facilities] 
inner join 
    [Rooms] on Room_Facilities.Room_ID = Rooms.Room_ID
where 
    Building_ID = 'LDS' 
    and Room_Facilities.Facility_ID = 'C' 
    and Room_Facilities.Facility_ID = 'V'
```

Comment: How can one Room_Facilities row have two different Faciliti_ID values? I think you're looking for Rooms rows which have both the 'C' and 'V' facilities. Also, are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include basic table design and sample data. People are confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes i am using sql server. This question has now been solved, thanks

Comment: FYI, in general, you want to use the [tag:sql-server] tag, not [tag:sql]. [tag:sql] is for the international standard SQL language itself, not for the Microsoft SQL Server product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to join with two records in the `Room_Facilities` table, like:

```
select distinct 
    room.Room_ID 
from 
    [Rooms] room
    join [Room_Facilities] facility1 ON room.Room_ID = facility1.Room_ID
    join [Room_Facilities] facility2 ON room.Room_ID = facility2.Room_ID
where 
    room.Building_ID = 'LDS' 
    and facility1.Facility_ID = 'C' 
    and facility2.Facility_ID = 'V'
```

This is since any `Facility_ID` can't be both equal to `'C'` and equal to `'V'`, but a record in the `Rooms` table can be referenced by multiple records in  `Room_Facilities`. This is why they are stored in different tables, with `Room_Facilities` referencing the `Room_ID` which (I assume) uniquely determines the entry in `Rooms`. People refer to this as a [one-to-many relationship](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s780ea06(v=vs.71).aspx#dvmscone-to-manyrelationships).

(A side note, people usually don't name tables with plural names)

Comment: Also, I don't think the other people actually read your question. Using `IN` won't solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, yes you are spot on with your understanding of the question. However, i have tried this sql, and it gives me with the error:
 "The multi-part identifier "Room_Facilities.Room_ID" could not be bound."

And as for the table names, this is a group project, so there will be quite alot of errors like that :)

Comment: Yes i fiddled around with it, I got it to work. Thanks alot for your help! Saved ALOT of my time.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use IN

```
select distinct Room_Facilities.Room_ID from [Room_Facilities] inner join [Rooms]
on Room_Facilities.Room_ID = Rooms.Room_ID
where Building_ID = 'LDS' and 
Room_Facilities.Facility_ID  IN ('C','V')
```

EDIT: [Here's a sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7df3/1), granted not with your exact schema.

Comment: It does. Added Fiddle example.

Comment: OP is asking for rooms that have BOTH a `C` AND a `V` facility - your query only shows rooms that have one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives to Join would be `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT RF.Room_ID
FROM   [Room_Facilities] RF
       INNER JOIN [Rooms] R
         ON RF.Room_ID = R.Room_ID
WHERE  R.Building_ID = 'LDS'
       AND RF.Facility_ID IN ( 'C', 'V' )
GROUP  BY RF.Room_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT RF.Facility_ID) = 2;
```

or `INTERSECT`

```
SELECT Room_ID
FROM   [Rooms]
WHERE  Building_ID = 'LDS'
INTERSECT
SELECT Room_ID
FROM   [Room_Facilities]
WHERE  Facility_ID = 'C'
INTERSECT
SELECT Room_ID
FROM   [Room_Facilities]
WHERE  Facility_ID = 'V'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want OR, since it can't be two values. Then just group those with parens to keep the `AND` working properly.

```
select distinct Room_Facilities.Room_ID from [Room_Facilities] inner join [Rooms]
on Room_Facilities.Room_ID = Rooms.Room_ID
where Building_ID = 'LDS' and 
 (Room_Facilities.Facility_ID  = 'C' OR Room_Facilities.Facility_ID = 'V')
```

Comment: I dont want to select a room that has either C or V, i need a room that has BOTH C and V

Answer (score 0):

<strike>One must remember that `AND` condition in `SQL` query doesn't actually apply to the statement as a human tend to think. SQL evaluates conditions on a row-basis so in your case you can't have two distinct values in one row - right?</strike>

What I mean is in one row you can't have `Facility_ID` both `'C'` and `'V'`.

What you want to do is use `IN` operator to give a list of possible values this column can have so that it matches your `WHERE` condition.

It's done by

```
WHERE Building_ID = 'LDS' AND Facility_ID IN ('C', 'V')
```

Or you could just as well use `OR` - which is actually a longer version (by characters in code) but not necessairly in case of performance - database has to transform the query above anyways (see `EXPLAIN` for details). The code would look like

```
WHERE Building_ID = 'LDS' AND ( Facility_ID = 'C' OR Facility_ID = 'V' )
```

Remember about parentheses, since you want to retrieve rows that have `Building_ID = 'LDS'` and one of values `'C' or 'V'` for `Facility_ID`.

**Edit**

I've probably misunderstood the question assuming you want to list all rooms that have either facility `C` or `V`. If you need both facilities you must `JOIN` twice to the same table using the same condition and alias those tables, then in `WHERE` clause put

```
alias1.Facility_ID = 'C' AND alias2.Facility_ID = 'V'
```

**Important note** I'd consider creating a 1 to many relationship with a table that would store facilities for every room.